# html - change number of columns and rows with a fixed size as the size of page changes

Tags: html, css

let's say i have 20 items and i want to display those in rows and in columns(basically in a table) in a html page. If the width of the page is 1360px and the width of each item is 128px then there would be 10 columns and 2 rows as shown below.

[image]

and if the width of the page is decreased to 1024px then there would be 8 columns in the first and second row and 4 columns in the third row as shown below

[image]

basically i want to change the number of rows and columns for a given number of items dynamically to fit the page given that the height and width of each cell is 128x128 pixels.

Comment: Instead of using table cells, you can use div tags with the CSS property display:inline-block.

Comment: using table would've been much easier though..

Comment: are all those cells single lonely element or is there a match with row and column as table data needs ? if not table-data, use inline-block or float elements and eventually mediaquerie to set breaking point

Comment: do you have any reference i can use... coz it's 3 am and i'm sleepcoding..

Comment: Tables are fixed elements, their table cell widths may adjust according to the table element's width but you can't have it magically add columns without some sort of scripting. So the question that needs to be answered is: is this data tabular? Or to make it really simple: what data are you trying to display on the page this way? Answer that and I can give you the answer you need.

Comment: i'm trying to make  file manager.. like the one they use in windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stick to CSS1 you just need to float items. You don't *have* to give them a set width though people do tend to work better with grids. You simply won't have the flexibility to display items using a table unless you always want to force people to view items in a details fashion...

**CSS**

```
#files > div
{
 float: left;
 width: 150px;
}
```

**(X)HTML**

```
<div id="files">
<div><span>File01.ext</span></div>
<div><span>File02.ext</span></div>
<div><span>File03.ext</span></div>
<div><span>File04.ext</span></div>
<div><span>File05.ext</span></div>
<div><span>File06.ext</span></div>
<div><span>File07.ext</span></div>
<div><span>File08.ext</span></div>
<div><span>File09.ext</span></div>
<div><span>File10.ext</span></div>
<div><span>File11.ext</span></div>
<div><span>File12.ext</span></div>
<div><span>File13.ext</span></div>
<div><span>File14.ext</span></div>
<div><span>File15.ext</span></div>
<div><span>File16.ext</span></div>
<div><span>File17.ext</span></div>
<div><span>File18.ext</span></div>
<div><span>File19.ext</span></div>
</div>
```

If you want to really make sure every pixel is used and you don't have to worry about a high level of compatibility then you can use [CSS3 Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).